# Using variable within a literal

Tags: actionscript-3

In my code I need to declare notationArr[1](http://sudrap.org/paste/text/44915/) but I'm getting this error: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

```
if ((notationArr[1].length == 2) && ((notationArr[1].charCodeAt(0) >= 97) && notationArr[1].charCodeAt(0) <= 104) && ((notationArr[1].charCodeAt(1) >= 49) && notationArr[1].charCodeAt(1) <= 56)) {
    if (pieces.d3.man == "") {
        pieces.notationArr[1].man.y = pieces.d4.y;

    }
}
```

Here, pieces is an object.

Edit: More code: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/44915/

Comment: Please add the code where you compose your `notationArr` and `pieces` variables

Comment: Have you tried pieces[notationArr[1]].man.y?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but have you tried regex? `[a-h][0-8]` might be easier to read than comparing char codes.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers. Yes, i tried pieces pieces[notationArr[1]].man.y   it didn t work.

Comment: I don't see `str` and `txt` defined anywhere.

Comment: they are declared above functions. i can send the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many variables in your little code piece was not properly declared and/or initialized.  You can only access properties or methods (every time you write `something.something`, that's the part after the .) on existing Objects, but not if the variable you are trying to access contains `null`.

**EDIT**

Having read your longer code piece, there could be several `null` variables, but your problem is probably what @AsTheWormTurns mentioned in his comment above:

```
pieces.notationArr[1].man
```

will try to access an array called notationArr that is **a member of pieces**, instead of **using an evaluation of the content of notationArr[1]** to find out which member of pieces to access.  It should be:

```
pieces[notationArr[1]].man
```

Comment: with pieces[notationArr[1]].man I'm getting this error: Cannot create property y on String.

Comment: then you have assigned a String value to pieces.{something}.man.  You can avoid this kind of issue if you create a custom class "Piece" that contains statically typed member variables (and one of type "Man", which would be another custom class), and store instances of that class instead of using dynamic Objects.  Check out Adobe's tutorial on creating a class: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html

Comment: sorry, but could you explain "statically typed member variables" or could you give an example? i know a little about classes.

Comment: A statically typed member is a variable or method that belongs to the class and only accepts values of a certain kind. You should _really_ start with that tutorial.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explaining. could you look at this code: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/44950/  I'm still getting errors.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding: I meant "statically typed", not "create static variables". There is a big difference: Static typing means defining the type of data the variable can hold, so the compiler will complain when you try to set a wrong value.  All _your_ variables are Objects, so they can have pretty much every possible value! A static variable, on the other hand, is a variable that is assigned to the class instead of an object instance. Please read up on object-oriented programming. I can't explain that to you - we'd be spending the next couple of days, if not weeks.